# Apache Not Cacheing Images

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
# EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I am using the above code in my .htaccess, but Page Speed Insights, GtMetrix etc are still saying my images not being cached. I tried various different examples posted and nothing is working. My host saids the issue is outside their scope... Any tips or direction to go in to try and diagnose the issue?

Comment: Is it just image or all the files? Did you check mod_expires is enabled?

Comment: its just image. i assume its on as its cacheing other files. not sure how to check not included in php info and commands i found on here for ssh give errors